# sorting input numbers in ascending order in python

Tags: python, list

```
name = int(input('>>>'))
ascending_order = name.split(', ')
ascending_order.sort()
print(ascending_order)
```

I am having error in line 1: int(input(">>>")

`name = int(input('>>>'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int()`

Comment: I bet you’re typing numbers separated by a comma. If so, a comma cannot be converted to an `int` so do the conversion after / during the split.

Comment: If the input is a comma-delimited list of numbers, you can't have int() applied to the input.  You need `name = input('>>>')`.  You need to then convert each element of ascending_order  to an int after the split.

Comment: Why are you casting the input to an integer? If you want to split something, you need to be using a string, `str(input('>>>')`

Comment: Split first, convert each number to int after

Comment: @I_keep_getting_downvoted: The `str` is implied and not needed.

Comment: @S3DEV o yeah lol I am being dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- with string conversion into integer:

  ```
  name = input('>>>')
  ascending_order = name.split(',')
  for i in range(len(ascending_order)):
       ascending_order[i] = int(ascending_order[i])
  ascending_order = sorted(ascending_order, reverse=True)
  print(ascending_order)
  ```
- without string conversion into integer:

  ```
  name = input('>>>')
  ascending_order = name.split(',')
  ascending_order = sorted(ascending_order, reverse=True)
  print(ascending_order)
  ```

Comment: What about something more concise like: `asc = sorted([int(i) for i in name.split(‘,’)])`?

Comment: You did the same thing but the technique you have used is list comprehension. and one more thing now its fine `asc = sorted([int(i) for i in name.split(',')], reverse=True)` .